# how to view different tables in a table interface using php and sqli

Tags: php, sql, database

I trying to add 3 tables for to fetch data from 3 table individually. I did mine and seem to have errors, kindly need some help, posting my code i have done but seem to be having errors been trying to have three table interface in one page to fetch 3 different tables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ecommerce";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    enter code here
    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, email FROM tbl_member";
    $results = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td> </tr>";
         }
         echo "</table>";
    } else {
         echo "0 results";

    }
    $conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>



<html>
<head>
<style>

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ecommerce";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


//  $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, email FROM tbl_member";
//  $result = $conn->query($sql);

//  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      //   echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
         // output data of each row
        //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          //   echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td> </tr>";
        // }
      //   echo "</table>";
//  } else {
   //echo "0 results";



    $sql = "SELECT memberid, plan, start_date, end_date,  FROM tbl_orders";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
             echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
             // output data of each row
             while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["memberid"]. "</td><td>" . $row["plan"]. "</td><td>" . $row["start_date"]. "</td><td>" . $row["end_date"]. "</td> </tr>";
         }
             echo "</table>";
    } else {
             echo "0 results";

    }

$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```